# ASP.NET WEB API Multiple Interfaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, service, interface, asp.net-web-api

I am designing ASP.NET WEB API service with two interfaces. First interface is read-only and second one is admin interface (to be used with MVC app) with full CRUD support. Does anyone know where I can get more information on such setup, any tutorials, walk thought, sample design document?

Also does it worth splitting these into two interfaces or keep them in same? But problem is that in read-only I expose 2-3 properties for every object while for admin there are 10-15?

Similar setup for WCF or design spec will do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your wanting to do, may I suggest rather than having one URL, i.e. \dataStuff\dataView split off into another view, maybe \dataStuff\edit\ which only admin's have access to, can be done like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public ActionResult edit()
{
    return View();
}
```

then next to each data element that your viewing add the following to ONLY admin's through use of User.IsInRole

```
@foreach (var item in Model.dataTable)
{
    @* 
    write a value from the data table here
    *@
    @Html.ActionLink("edit", "edit").If(User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
    <br/>
}
```

obviously you don't have to display your data like this, I'm just showing that you add to the end of each element of the database an edit ActionLink IF the user is admin.

This allows your admin to view data like a user and also have the added functionality they need. Code re-use is better than a single view which has two states, Admin and non Admin.

Sorry if this isn't the best explanation, fairly new to MVC

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this concept is sometimes called CQRS. 
Sample: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: Please read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)